# How to change the colours of sparkline axes individually

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting, microsoft-excel-2013

I found the [following code (in the office docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197606.aspx) which allows me to change the axis colour of a group of sparklines:

```
Sub AxisColor()
    'The sparkline group
    Dim oSparkGroup As SparklineGroup
    'Loop through the sparkline groups on the sheet
    For Each oSparkGroup In Range("A2:C2").SparklineGroups
        'Show the axis
        oSparkGroup.Axes.Horizontal.Axis.Visible = True
        'Set the color of the axis to the color of cell A8
        oSparkGroup.Axes.Horizontal.Axis.Color.Color = Range("A8").Interior.Color
    Next oSparkGroup
End Sub
```

However I have a (single) group of 60 sparklines and the axis is going to either be above or below the line (it differs case by case). I want to have *different* colours for an axis that is above all the data (i.e. a max) and for an axis that is below all the data (i.e. a min). Is this possible?

I suspect that I might need to break the sparkline group into 60 individual groups. If someone can show me how to do that (via VBA or otherwise) then I can easily adapt the code above for my purposes.

Comment: I've inspected the objects in the above code in the watch window while debugging and found no way to alter individual item properties. And I've search for documentation about splitting the groups and found nothing.

Comment: @Raystafarian no you can't change the axis colour manually unfortunately. You can't even change them as a group manually, which is why the docs provide the vba code linked to.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you're already addressing each group. Throw an `if` in before setting the color if you want a different color depending on the location.

Comment: I only have *one* group, in this group there are multiple spark lines (i.e. many cells). I want to change the colour of the axis for individual sparklines with-in this one group. If you can help me break this one group into one group per sparkline, then yes I can use an if statement to achieve what I want.

Comment: You are addressing each group `For Each oSparkGroup In Range("A2:C2").SparklineGroups`

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks, I know that. I only have **one** group. One single group. The code comes straight out of the docs (linked), and in their example they have 3 groups. I only have 1. 1 group, containing 60 sparklines. If I had 60 groups each containing 1 sparkline then yes, the `foreach` would iterate through them all. This is why I would happily accept an answer that shows me how to break 1 group of 60 sparklines into 60 groups of 1 sparkline each. I have 1 group of 60 because that requires making the sparkline manually once. 60 groups of 1 means making 60 sparklines manually.

Comment: @Raystafarian but the items are not in a collection so do you know how to iterate over them?

Comment: documentation doesn't say it needs to be in a collection [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195996.aspx). If you want, please provide a copy (sanitized) of the data and I'll see what I can do; I don't have any sparkline workbooks to try it on.

Comment: Thanks. In cells `A1:F20` make some random data that crosses 0 (e.g. `=randbetween(-10,10)`). Then in cells `A21:F21` make a normal sparkline that references `A1:F20` for data. Use any rules you like to choose which sparklines should have a different coloured axis.

Comment: Note that if you do this and want to use the doc code example I posted then change `"A2:C2"` to either `"A21"` or ``"A21:F21"` or anything in between, it won't matter. Also change `... = Range("A8").Interior.Color` to `... = RGB(255,0,0)` for example